# How to add a new apache tika Detector?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm use Apache Tika 2.4.1 version.
I created a new detector.

```java
public class SvgDetector implements Detector {

    @Override
    public MediaType detect(InputStream input, Metadata metadata) throws IOException {
        String text = IOUtils.toString(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        if (text.startsWith("<svg") && text.endsWith("</svg>")) {
            return MediaType.parse("image/svg+xml");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like below

```
String mimeTypeValue = new Tika(new SvgDetector()).detect(multipartFile.getInputStream());
```

But there is a problem, `Cannot invoke "org.apache.tika.mime.MediaType.toString()" because the return value of "org.apache.tika.detect.Detector.detect(java.io.InputStream, org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata)" is null`

file is `.png` type, not `.svg` file. I'm guessing the original detector was not loaded, but replaced by the SVG detector.

Please tell me what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You should list the new class in a services file, the same way as you would for a parser, see https://tika.apache.org/2.4.1/parser_guide.html

Comment: @Gagravarr I use Tika through Maven, and the link you provided mentioned modifying the `tika-parsers/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.tika.parser.Parser` file, which seems to be Modified the jar package? Is there any other way? If this is the only way, how should I modify the files inside the jar?

Comment: Tika loads all the files with that name it finds on the classpath, so just pop a service file with the same name in your jar which lists your class

Comment: @Gagravarr Sorry, the official documentation feels too rudimentary and I don't quite understand it. Can you have sample code or links to related tutorials?

Comment: Any Java Service Loader tutorial should be fine. An example of a custom parser and detector in https://github.com/Gagravarr/VorbisJava/tree/master/tika

Comment: I introduced tika into a module of the springboot project, and the code is the same as the github link you provided. But tika only uses the custom SvgDetector for detection, not the built-in Detector

Comment: For example, when a file is of type `image/png`, Tika only uses `SvgDetector`, so no file type is detected.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-IdentifyingwhatDetectorsyourTikainstallsupports

Comment: I checked the tutorial, but the above code is outdated, for example the method `parser.getDetectors()` is no longer available. I added the startup parameter `-Dorg.apache.tika.service.error.warn=true` to the JVM virtual machine, and no error was reported

Comment: From the results, the `src\main\resources\META-INF\services` configuration file takes effect, but other built-in detectors are not loaded, only the SVG detector is loaded

Comment: Any chance the other services are getting clobbered in your uber jar?  You'll need this in your shade-plugin: <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />